# Why this MySQL Query Not working?

Tags: mysql

I have wrote MySQL query to check any rows between given start and finish time, but it doesn't work, please someone help me to find this error?

query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_id='".$input['guard']."'
AND (start_time >= '".$startDateTime."' OR finish_time <= ".$finishDateTime."'
```

error:

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 (SQL: SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='13' AND (start_time >= '2014-10-20 10:30:00' OR finish_time <= '2014-10-20 21:30:00' )

Comment: Well it tells you where the error is - line 3, and it's an issue with the character `"`. I think we need to see the surrounding code, because clearly the concatenation is wrong

Comment: There is a single quote `'` missing at the end - should be `... <= '".$finishDateTime."'` ?

Comment: @Doctus sorry I found the error I missed that (start_time >= '".$startDateTime."' OR finish_time <= ".$finishDateTime."' row close bracket

Comment: You miss a parenthesis at the end of the query.

Comment: you can use '$finishDateTime' too. Easier IMO

Answer (score 0):

```
  $guard=$input['guard'];
  $sql="SELECT *FROM users WHERE user_id='$guard' AND (start_time >='$startDateTime' OR finish_time <='$finishDateTime')";
```